# Why can I define a static constant that depends on another static constant in the same type, but not for properties?

Tags: swift, static-variables

I am familiar with getting an error when trying to access `self` before all the properties are initialized. One thing I never understood is why I can initialize `static` constants with dependencies on other `static` properties in the same `type` without any error.

What is the reason about this behavior? Why does defining `static` constants don't give me a compile time error and property constants does?

Some code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    static let myStatic = 1
    // No error on this line...
    static let myStaticPlusOne = myStatic + 1

    let myInstance = 1
    // ... But a compile time error on this one! What makes the difference?
    let myInstancePlusOne = myInstance + 1
}
```

There *has* to be a time when this struct gets loaded into the memory or whatever at sometime, loading the static variables. I see this time exactly the same as the time a new instance is created of a `type`. I can not clearly see the difference between those two. Both have a time where one property is initialized and the other isn't. Than why can I still have access to my static variable from another static variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type and instance.

- The type MyStruct always exists. `static` properties belong to the type. So they just sit there and can do anything they like or be related in any way. Okay, yes, it has to come into existence when the program starts, but under the hood the static property initializers are all `lazy` so it's okay for one to depend on another (not in a circular way of course).
- An instance of MyStruct is a thing that has to be created, each time you say `MyStruct(...)`. When you say that, the instance properties must be initialized. An instance (not `static`) property belongs to the instance. So its initializer's value cannot refer to `self` because `self` is exactly what we are in the middle of creating, i.e. the instance. This line:

  ```
  let myInstancePlusOne = myInstance + 1
  ```

  ...really means

  ```
  let myInstancePlusOne = self.myInstance + 1
  ```

  ...but that is exactly what you are not allowed to say; at the time you are initializing this property there is no `self` yet, it is what you are initializing. And you can work around this by *declaring* that property `lazy` (with other adjustments in the syntax).

Comment: By the time you're creating a type, the type isn't created yet, so how come you're allowed to access the type's variable? I still can't tell the difference. Both have to be created ie both will have a phase that can be described as 'we are in the middle of creating'. Both have one property referring to another

Comment: 'The type MyStruct always exists' I know that in Java classes are loaded at runtime, not sure about swift. However, there has to be a time loading the class. I don't see exactly the difference between the type and an instance. An instance needs explicitly be created, the type implicitly on first access (questionmark, not sure about this) (at some point). `self` refers to the current working type, whereas `MyType` refers to the current working `type`. I see `self` just the way as `type`, not sure if this is correct

Comment: @Honey Yes, I have exactly the same thoughts. It needs to be created sometime.

Comment: Yes, it is "created" at startup, but technically its static properties are initialized lazily so they can depend on one another (not in a circular way obviously). You could make your instance property legal by declaring it `lazy` too (with some other syntactic changes).

Comment: @matt Ah! I see it, the static properties are initialized lazy! That explains it all, if you could that to the answer I will accept it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#ID263 gave me even more details :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the following two reasons:

- Every global property is computer lazily. The non-intuitive thing is that they don't need to be marked with `lazy`.
- Circular dependency is not allowed

---

A more simpler example of what Matt said:

```
class X {
    static var a = 10
    static var b = 20
}

class Y {
    static var a = 10 * Y.b
    static var b = 20
}

class Z {
    static var a = 10 * Z.b
    static var b = 20 * Z.a // ERROR: Type 'Z' has no member 'a' 
}
```

class `Z` is invalid because you have a circular dependency. But I don't think the error is not clear.

That means the compiler will try to figure out the dependencies and start building the type from a value that doesn't depend on anything, then move onto building the other type properties. But if it can't do that, it would error out!

As you mentioned in the comments. The [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID2630) say:

> Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a
>   similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored
>   properties, global constants and variables do not need to be marked
>   with the lazy modifier.
>
> Local constants and variables are never computed lazily.

---

The following will pass the compiler, yet it will crash upon accessing a property

```
class C {
    lazy var a : Int = {
        let _a = self.b + 30
        return _a
    }()

    lazy var b : Int = {
        let _b = self.a + 20
        return _b
    }()
}

let d = C().a // ERROR!
```

So as you can see for both you need to build either an instance/type based on a stored value, then compute other properties off that.